# PHP count elements in formatted string

Tags: php, arrays, string

This has been boggling my mind for a day now so I need some help.
In a given string such as the follwing:

```
$str = 'a:1:{s:8:"post_tag";a:5:{
i:460;a:5:{s:11:"wpseo_title";s:8:"demodemo";s:10:"wpseo_desc";s:8:"demodemo";s:13:"wpseo_bctitle";s:8:"demodemo";s:13:"wpseo_noindex";s:7:"default";s:21:"wpseo_sitemap_include";s:1:"-";}
i:459;a:5:{s:11:"wpseo_title";s:8:"testtest";s:10:"wpseo_desc";s:8:"testtest";s:13:"wpseo_bctitle";s:8:"testtest";s:13:"wpseo_noindex";s:7:"default";s:21:"wpseo_sitemap_include";s:1:"-";}
i:462;a:5:{s:11:"wpseo_title";s:7:"bikey77";s:10:"wpseo_desc";s:7:"bikey77";s:13:"wpseo_bctitle";s:7:"bikey77";s:13:"wpseo_noindex";s:7:"default";s:21:"wpseo_sitemap_include";s:1:"-";}
i:463;a:5:{s:11:"wpseo_title";s:7:"dimitra";s:10:"wpseo_desc";s:7:"dimitra";s:13:"wpseo_bctitle";s:7:"dimitra";s:13:"wpseo_noindex";s:7:"default";s:21:"wpseo_sitemap_include";s:1:"-";}
i:464;a:5:{s:11:"wpseo_title";s:8:"dimitra1";s:10:"wpseo_desc";s:8:"dimitra1";s:13:"wpseo_bctitle";s:8:"dimitra1";s:13:"wpseo_noindex";s:7:"default";s:21:"wpseo_sitemap_include";s:1:"-";}
}}';
```

how do I count the number of substrings that begin with i:XXX... and end with ...;} ??

Substring example:

`i:460;a:5:s:11:"wpseo_title";s:8:"demodemo";s:10:"wpseo_desc";s:8:"demodemo";s:13:"wpseo_bctitle";s:8:"demodemo";s:13:"wpseo_noindex";s:7:"default";s:21:"wpseo_sitemap_include";s:1:"-";}`

Comment: Can you unserialize the string and count the rows?

Comment: I'm surprised at the similarity of the question to [this example of XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Perhaps you can also suggest a solution? Or are you only being smart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're dealing with a serialized array, so...

```
$data = unserialize($str);
echo count($data['post_tag']);
```

Comment: Tried unserialize already, returns 0. Also, it should probably be count($data['wpseo_title']) since post_tag only occurs once in the string.

Comment: @bikey77 `post_tag` contains 5 `wpseo_title` that's why `count($arr['post_tag']);`.

Comment: @bikey77 http://3v4l.org/QJA8K

Comment: Thats very strange, because I tried again just 1 minute ago and it returns 0. Obviously I'm doing something wrong so I'll accept your answer as the correct one (being the 1st answer, although Yogesh gave the same answer as well). Many, many thanks.

Comment: @bikey77 Your serialized data may contain *line breaks*, which invalidates the serialized format. Make sure you're not altering the serialized data in any way by inserting line breaks or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This is serialized data, unserialize it

```
$arr = unserialize($str);
echo count($arr['post_tag']);
```

Comment: I only accepted deceze's answer as the correct answer simply because he replied before you although they are identical. Many thanks.